# simple login form error VB 2010

Tags: vb.net

I've search a lot of resources and couldn't fix it.
My problem is when I click the button event the next form doesn't show and also I want to close my login form at the same time.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Dim firstname As String = ""
    Dim lastname As String = ""
    Dim ara As Boolean = False
    cn = New OleDbConnection(con)
    cn.Open()
    Dim user As String
    Dim pass As String
    user = TextBox1.Text
    pass = TextBox2.Text
    With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "Select * from users WHERE username='" & user & "' AND password='" & pass & "'"
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If rdr.HasRows Then
            ara = True
            While rdr.Read()

                firstname = rdr("firstname").ToString
                lastname = rdr("lastname").ToString

                lib_name = firstname + lastname
            End While

            If ara = True Then

                Form2.Show()
                Me.Close()
                x = True

            Else
                MsgBox("  Access Denied!" + Environment.NewLine + "Sorry, username or password is incorrect!")
            End If
        End If
    End With

    cn.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
```

Comment: close de connexion before showing Form2 and closing the login form

Comment: Read [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?499888-WinForms-Login).

Comment: I a real application, you would never store a password as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

1 : You are opening the gates of **SQL INJECTION**. [Read more](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) . Instead of passing values directly in your query, pass parameters first and use them later(For unknown reason, the code formatting is not working below) :

```
Dim cmd as New OleDbCommand("Select * from users WHERE username=@user AND password=@pass" , con)
With cmd

.Parameters.Add("@user", OleDbType.Varchar).Value = user

.Parameters.Add("@user", OleDbType.Varchar).Value = password
End With
```

2 : Your `If` statement will only work `IDateReader.HasRows` returns true and if `ara=True` which is unnecessary. `.HasRows` is a boolean, you don't need to create another boolean and pass the value to it. However, the rest of your code will only execute if your conditions match

3 : `Form1.Close` and `AnotherForm.Show` will never work if in your **Project Proerties** , `Shutdown Mode` is set to `On main window close`(by default). Either change it to `On Explicit window close` or `On last window close` **or** change

`Me.CLose` To

`Me.Hide`

4 : In order to reduce too much code , you can use `Using Statement` :

```
Using cmd as New SqlCommand("Select * from users WHERE username=@user AND password=@pass" , con)
'''codes here
End Using
''Now no need to call cmd.Dispose
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Am I reading this right? Are you really posting code that is "not working" as an answer?

Comment: @Mary , ahem , what did I miss ?

Comment: Didn't your edit fix it? Can you remove the sentence For unknown reasons...

Comment: @Mary Ow sorry, when I posted the answer first, the formatting wasn't there , don't know why :( .. However, I agree I did make a few more mistakes . Thank you so much for pointing 'em out